# reversing a micro motor by reversing two pins - one Source and one sink?

Tags: power, motor

can I use this configuration of two pins to run a micro motor ,so I be able to change the polarity of the current (by the code itself-one time out pin1-high out pin2 - low , while next time one low two high!) every time I would like ?(and by changing the polarity OF THE CURRENT to the motor it will revers it) !

Thank's !

Comment: For interest - how micro is "micro" and what is the motor used and application? If you need more power an H bridge driver can be built for tens of cents (and some ICs are low cost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**Required:**  

Drive micro-motor directly from two processor pins.   

 - Pin 1 high / Pin 2 low for one direction.  
 - Pin 1 low / Pin 2 high for other direction.**
```

This is not a very good idea if it can be avoided but yes, you can operate a motor that way,  providing that the motor current is low enough to meet the pin current ratings. It would have to be a very small motor to achieve this.

Take careful note of the current versus voltage drive capabilities of the processor concerned. While a pin may be shown as being able to source or sing 5 or 10 or 20 mA, this is accompanied by a voltage rise for a sink and voltage drop for a source, so at higher currents lower voltages will be available.

A danger is that motor noise may affect the processor.
Placing a small capacitor across the motor will help, and driving the motor through a small resistor from each pin will also help keep noise away from the processor. But depending on the motor used this may not be enough.
The series resistors will drop some voltage and so are limited in maximum allowable size.
The parallel capacitor will slow the direction transition - the larger the capacitor the slower the change.

Using drivers or "buffers" which are higher current rated would allow a larger motor to be driven and would help isolate the processor from the motor noise.

Ask further if any idea here sounds useful.

---

Added: Had a discussion with Gerben (below).
I'd avoided mentioning "catch diodes" but this is an add on that can help.
From each pin add a small Schottky diode* from pin to Vcc and pin to ground so that all 4 diodes are reverse biased.
(ie Cathode goes to Vcc = line on diode on upper diodes.
Anode goes to ground on "lower" diodes. )
These diodes are usually non conducting. If motor operation or switching causes spikes that rise above Vcc or below ground these diodes will conduct (slightly) before  the internal protection diodes do. This is not ideal but can help.
As Gerben notes, when reversing the motor, driving BOTH pins to ground until the motor has stopped and then applying reversing polarity can help. Also driving both high will do the same. There are pros and cons with either method.

- eg [**BAT54** surface mount](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds11005.pdf),   [**BAT48 through hole**](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000768.pdf), [1N581x](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?k=schottky+diode+1n581&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=1&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)  or similar.

Comment: You also need to add some clamping diodes to eliminate flyback, which is the sudden voltage spike seen across an inductive load when its supply voltage is suddenly reduced or removed. I did this on my project where I was driving the tiny lavet stepper motor inside an analog clock. I added diode to clamp the voltage to VCC. Clamping to ground  was done by setting both pins to LOW before any further movement.

Comment: A problem with using diodes is that the motor polarity reverses. I considered suggesting Schottky diodes to gnd and VCC from each pin but decided to offer the cct as seen and see if the OP shows interest. It can then be refined. You can add an H bridge driver with jellybean transistors for very little $ indeed but providing detail on this initially is just liable to confuse.

Comment: thank you very much guys !                                                                                                you are fantastic  !!!